# How do you create a model using opencv in django?

Tags: python, django, opencv, face-detection

Anybody know who to integrate django and opencv(cv2) together. My goal is to create an model that can store the user and a picture of them. I first tried just using
 `UserPicture.objects.create(user=request.user, picture=image)` but that wouldn't work because the function was not taking request as a parameter. Should I create an APIView somehow? Anyways, here is the code I am using for the opencv class:

```
class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()
    
    def create_facial_boundary(self, image, cascadeClassifier, color, emotion):
        grayScaled = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        face = cascadeClassifier.detectMultiScale(grayScaled, 1.1, 10)
        coords = []
        for (x, y, w, h) in face:
            cv2.rectangle(image, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color)
            roi_gray = grayScaled[y : y+h, x: x+w]
            cv2.putText(image, emotion, (x, y-4), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 2, (255, 255, 255))
            coords = [x, y, w, h]
        self.update_time()
        return coords, image

    def detect_face(self, image, cascadeClassifier):
      color = {"green" : (0, 145, 25)}
      coords, image = self.create_facial_boundary(image, cascadeClassifier, color["green"], "ExText")
      image = cv2.flip(image, 1)
      return image

    def update_time(self):
        time.sleep(5)

    def get_user_face(self):
        success, frame  = self.video.read()
        # img_file = "User-Face.jpg"
        frame = self.detect_face(frame, cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml'))
        new_frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        _, image = cv2.imencode(".jpg", new_frame)
        return image
    
    def get_user_emotion():
        pass

    def get_frame(self):
        success, frame = self.video.read()
        image_flip = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image_flip)
        return jpeg.tobytes()
    
    

def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')

def get_image(camera):
    image = camera.get_user_face()
    return image

        
def video_feed(request):
    while True:
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()),
                    content_type='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Answer (score 0):

First, the way you are opening the image is not recommended, use `from PIL import Image` to open it (ithis is the recommended way when using `opencv` and `requests` together).
Second, check if you are really receiving the image in your request.